# Is it natural to say "feel embarrassed"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Guy 1: So how are you? It's been a long time.

Guy 2: I'm okay. Yeah, I just feel a little embarrassed about everything that happened last time. I hope you can forgive me.

Is the use of "feel" natural here? Or would it be much more natural if the sentence was "Yeah, I'm just a little embarrassed about everything that happened last time."?

Comment: Both versions sound completely natural to me.

Comment: You can `be` embarrassed or you can `feel` embarrassed. Both normal and natural.

Comment: "I'm just a little embarrassed about what happened last time." Is even a more natural construction.  The use of feel is perfectly fine, also, and both constructions are commonly used.